# How can I make strtok include newlines at the end of a token?

Tags: c, string, ascii, strtok

In a program I am writing, I need to be able to tokenize a input text file into words, do some encoding, and then write to an output file. Problem is, I need to preserve the new lines.

The approach I was trying is to have strtok preserve the newlines at the end of a word, however, strtok will only include one newline character before moving on. If there is a following newline, it becomes its own token. How can I change this behavior so that tokens include all newlines before moving onto the next word?

```
int changeNewLine(char* p) {
    p = p + (strlen(p)-1);
    int newlines = 0;
        while(*p == '\n') {
            *p = '\0';
            newlines++;
            p--;
        }
    return newlines;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *inputfile = fopen(argv[1],"rw");
    FILE *outputfile = fopen("output.txt","wb");
    char buffer[128];
    char *token;
    char words[MAX_CODE][WORDLEN];
    int i = 0;
    unsigned short newlines[MAX_CODE];

    while(fgets(buffer, 128, inputfile)){
            token = strtok(buffer," ");
            while(token != NULL) {
                newlines[i] = changeNewLine(token);
                strcpy(words[i], token);
                i++;
                token = strtok(NULL," ");
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

Above is a fragment of my code. The idea is to count the number of newlines in a token, and then write them back out later.

Comment: Strtok is pretty ugly, perhaps you can use strspn or strcspn in a loop instead?

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` already does include newlines in the token, since you are using a delimiter string that does not contain the newline.  But in your program as it now is, you will never have more than one in a token because `fgets` reads (at most) one line at a time.  That's its whole purpose.  It will never give you a string containing two or more newlines, nor containing a newline anywhere other than the last character.

Your general alternatives are

1. to look ahead at subsequent lines in order to spot additional newlines, or
2. retrospectively update the previous line's newline count when encounter a line starting with a newline (and, therefore, containing nothing else).

Alternative (1) could include employing an altogether different approach to reading input, too, such as a block read with `fread()` or a character-at-a-time read with `fgetc()`.